# Instantiating global object in objective C when they're passed to a function. Confusion regarding object scope

Tags: objective-c, c, variables, cocos2d-iphone, instantiation

I'm new to Objective-C and C in general. I've been looking around and I couldn't find the solution to this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following global variables

`CCSprite* BackgroundImage;
CCSprite* BackgroundGhost;
CCSprite* Globe;
CCSprite* Logo;`

in my init I call a function and pass the global variables as parameters.

```
if(_ourDevice == iPad)
   {

       [self CustomCodeSetAssetForIpad:BackgroundImage ghost:BackgroundGhost TheGlobe:Globe AndTheLogo:Logo];


   }
```

Here is the code for CustomCodeSetAssetForIpad:

```
-(void) CustomCodeSetAssetForIpad:(CCSprite*) _Background ghost:(CCSprite*) _BackgroundGhosts TheGlobe:(CCSprite*)_Globes AndTheLogo:(CCSprite*) _Logos
{
    _Background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1028-768-sunray.png"];
    _BackgroundGhosts = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1028-768-sunray.png"];
    _Globes = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"BigGlobe.png"];
    _Logos  = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"DefaultLogo.png"];

    [_BackgroundGhosts setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0)];
    [_BackgroundGhosts setScale:2];
    [_BackgroundGhosts setOpacity:120];
    //[BackgroundGhost setPosition: CGPointMake(BackgroundGhost.position.x, BackgroundGhost.position.y-500)];

    [_BackgroundGhosts setPosition:CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize].width/2, -100)];

    [_Globes setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    [_Globes setScale:0.7];
    [_Globes setPosition:CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize].width/2, -260)];



    [_Logos setPosition:CGPointMake([self CenterOfTheScreen].x, [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize].height-[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize].height*0.2)]; 
    [_Logos setScale:0.05];


}
```

The first few lines instantiate the global variables that were passed. However when the function is done, the reference to those objects are lost. I thought when you pass a pointer to a function, as the object is instantiated, it would retain its reference to the instantiated object. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... Variables of type `classname *` are effectively references to instances of that class. So in your case, `_Background` is an instance reference passed *in* as an argument to your function. If you are trying to return multiple results from a function (via pointers), your arguments should really of type `classname **`, which is a pointer to a reference.

So the calling code would look like this:

```
CCSprite * background = nil ;
CCSprite * ghosts = nil ;
CCSprite * globes = nil ;
CCSprite * logos = nil ;
```

`[ self customCodeSetAssetForIpad:&background ghosts:&ghosts globes:&globes logos:&logos ] ;`

And your method looks like this:

```
-(void)customCodeSetAssetForIPad:(CCSprite**)background ghosts:(CCSprite**)backgroundhosts globe:globes logos:(CCSprite**)logos
{
    *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1028-768-sunray.png"];
    // ... the rest of your code ...
}
```

Also, I took the liberty of making your method name and variable names more objective-c like (methods and variables begin with lowercase letters)

**EDIT: I'd personally structure it like this:**

```
//
// World... global things go in here
//

@interface World

@property ( nonatomic, readonly, strong ) CCSprite * background ;

+(id)theWorld // accessor to get the global world object

@end

@implementation World
@synthesize CCSprite * background = _background ;

static World * __theWorld = nil ; // global variable to hold our shared global World instance

+(void)load
{
    // when this class is loaded, create our global world object
    __theWorld = [ [ [ self class ] alloc ] init ] ;
}

+(id)theWorld
{
    return __theWorld ;
}

// return the background sprite, creating it if it hasn't be created yet
-(CCSprite*)background
{
    if ( !_background) { _background = [ CCSprite spriteWithFile:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1028-768-sunray.png"] ; }
    return _background ;
}

@end
```

Comment: Objective-C definetly doesn't like `(Class *)*` in the function signature. I tried playing around with `(Class **)`. That still doesn't want to do it.

Comment: Also--this is sort of a non-standard pattern I would say.. Personally, I might create a "world" object with all the "globals" objects contained within as member variables. I would then use lazy initialization in accessors to initialize my member variables...

Comment: I know, these sprites are for quick testing. I was playing around with them and I noticed when a pointer of an object is passed to a function, its instantiation in the function is not retained. How do you override @synthesized accessors?

Comment: You just write the code--I wrote something I think is more "standard" in my answer. It shows overriding a synthesized accessor, and declaring storage for the variable. You can leave out the `@synthesize` directive if you're not writing your own accessors.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. It's beautiful. Your World class looks like a singleton. I want to learn more when it comes to Objective-C standards (everything from naming conventions to common patterns for solving problems) What resources would you recommend?

Comment: Singleton, yes. As for standards... I think there can be a lot of variation actually. but, Apple's coding conventions are here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html, and this looks promising: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php. Good luck.